# flutter pub publish: Could not find an option named "dry-run"

Tags: flutter, dart-pub

When publishing a pub package, the [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages) say to run the following command:

```
 flutter pub publish --dry-run
```

However, this is giving the following error:

> Could not find an option named "dry-run".
>
> Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter  -h') for available flutter
>   commands and options.

How do I run a "dry-run"?

*This is a self-answer Q&A after finding the answer. The answer is below.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update:

This command works now:

```
flutter pub publish --dry-run
```

#### Original answer

Use:

```
flutter pub pub publish --dry-run
```

Thanks to [this post](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33302#issuecomment-496003182) for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a Dart package you can use

```
dart pub publish --dry-run
```

Comment: the question was for flutter, not dart